# How do I navigate an unexpectedly toxic workplace environment at a brand new job?

Tags: new-job, company-culture, politics

I recently started a new software development job after taking a 50% pay cut at my previous company due to Covid. I had interned at my current company back in college, but they were unable to match other offers so I ended up working elsewhere for a while. When I first interned here, I wasn't involved in any office group chats, and generally wasn't really aware of it.

As a full-time developer now, I've been added to a variety of group chats that are used for work--and also for political discussion. I will say that I differ from the vast majority of my coworkers politically (I'm moderately left-leaning, they're mostly American Libertarian or Republican)--which is fine. I don't have issues with people of other political stripes. My coworkers, however, do. More specifically, they are VERY vocal about how opposed they are to people of my political bent. Essentially, the group chats that I've been invited to are 60% discussion of how much they hate anyone different than them politically (often in very explicit terms), and 40% work, so I cannot leave the group chats or ignore them.

At my two previous companies, this was explicitly against company policy. This company, however, is very small, and given that many people in leadership and management positions apparently see no problem with this I cannot really bring this up with anyone. The 'HR' department consists of one individual--the CEO. I've tried pushing back a little bit without outing myself. Asking work questions in the middle of these conversations to try and derail them does little good, and actively pushing back usually earns responses along the lines of "Well [X political group] is un-American and trying to destroy this country."

Unfortunately, I feel like I'm essentially stuck here for at least a few years. I graduated college in 2018 and have had 3 jobs then. My first job I left due to poor management and repeated 80-115 hour work-weeks being expected. The position I took after that was far better, up until Covid hit. They were a travel-related company and as such were hit extremely hard. A 50% paycut would have left me unable to pay rent or cover expenses. Now, I feel that if I start looking for a new job it will look like I'm simply job hopping, as I was at my second job for 6 months and have hardly been here for 2 months.

Should I just buckle down and deal with this for a 2-3 years and then begin looking for a new position? Bring this up with my manager (despite the fact that he is one of the individuals constantly deriding my politics as "F****** awful", "un-American", and talking about how angry he gets at people with my beliefs)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111616/discussion-on-question-by-kiith-how-do-i-navigate-an-unexpectedly-toxic-workplac).

Comment: Political persuasion is not a protected job class. Stick with it while looking for a tech company where the management tilts to the right.

Comment: @DavidHammen It's not a protected class, but there are things like "creating a hostile work environment" and "constructive dismissal".

Comment: You probably want to remove all the specific details from the question and just ask about the principle of the matter, i.e. knowing which particular political leanings you and your coworkers have is probably not relevant to the answer, what matters is that you have different leanings, that these are being discussed in work channels and that it seems like this situation is endorsed by management.

Comment: Is this work-from-home or in person?

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, that's a tough spot. Long term, it's a losing proposition. There is a huge cultural disconnect between you and your employer and your employer is behaving very unprofessionally in the first place.

Best you can do is to hunker down, do your job, stay out of any political discussion and keep looking at full throttle. Deal with the job hopping question when it comes up. Make sure you have a decent story and Covid actually makes it easier to sell. Some companies may care, but other's may be ok with it and you really have nothing to loose at this point.

One lesson to consider: You signed with an employer that you were utterly incompatible with. Make sure that doesn't happen again: make sure you covers this in the interview question that you ask and the research that you do.

Comment: Agreed it's always a good idea to try to discover as much about the culture as you can in an interview, but to be fair the OP probably did not have much of a selection of jobs, and even if the OP asked if politics were part of daily conversation I'm sure the answer would have been No.

Comment: "lLong term, it's a loosing proposition" ??? That grammatical mistake is fingernails on the chalkboard to me. That StackExchange does not allow me to even suggest a one character change is a **losing proposition** to me. Let the extra "o" in loosing go loose. The correct idiom is losing proposition.

Comment: @DavidHammen: fixed.

Comment: That said, talking politics during an interview is a good way to not get the job. It's also a good way to continue unemployment benefits; I strongly suspect that some of the candidates I have interviewed intentionally tanked the interview process. In addition to interviews, my employer requires candidates to give a presentation on a subject of their choice. One candidate went into a rant in the Q&A after the presentation on why females are (a) terrible engineers, and (b) even if they are, they should not be in the workplace, as their right place is getting pregnant and raising kids.

Comment: We did not hire that person.

Comment: @DavidHammen you should have - as a kitchen maid. That being said, there are people who live in all kinds of bubbles and assume everyone will agree with them on certain topics. All us internet "weirdos" need to exist somewhere in the real world too and my hypothesis is that nearly everyone will have at least one conviction a major portion of the general populous will find weird when exposed to in a short heated passionate flow.

Comment: @DavidHammen ah, what I actually wanted to mention as an improvement suggestion: Regarding covering this in interviews: I'd agree to not bring it up directly as that in itself can easily go in an unprofessional way or may you look unprofessional (and it's hard to get the truth out anyway, nobody will say 'yes' to "are you bullying by political affiliation?").  What you can do is ask to meet the team, try to have a team lunch or some other form of relatively free, open, casual conversations with colleagues and bosses to experience their casual day to day behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not engage politics in the chat. You will not gain, and you will lose productivity to it.
2. Demonstrate you are a nice, reliable person for a while— months at least.
3. When you get back into the workplace, if you do, and after you've built up a rapport with them, engage your coworkers in conversation 1:1. Be respectful and courteous. Don't outright put down their views. Listen mostly and ask questions designed to provoke their skeptical thought processes eventually. Example lines might be: "I think I see where you're coming from, but I think those people are well meaning as well. Have you ever talked to them?"; "Do you think 1/3 of the country wants to destroy it?"; "That's me you're talking about. I'm not so bad."

Eventually, if you want to stay at this company, it's better to politely and firmly stand up for yourself rather than bear it miserably. But, if you want to quit, then just do it.

Your manager is another matter. You have to be forthright with your manager, but not demanding. I would say, "I'm moderately liberal. Will you have a problem with me working here? You've expressed that I'm awful and unamerican. I assure you I'm not." Note that this speaks to your value personally, and is not making demands that people be silenced. The other employees are likely following your manager's lead, and if s/he relents, they might tone down too.

Answer (score -8):

1. Saying that these group chats about politics and other issues make this a toxic work place is a bit of a stretch. Many things can contribute to making a work place toxic, and I'd personally put this kind of thing pretty low on that list. People are entitled to their own opinions and views. Just because they're the opposite of yours doesn't make them toxic. Unless they're being outwardly and vocally xenophobic, racist, sexist, etc., etc. you'd have a hard time making a case for this being a toxic environment.
2. While it may be challenging to do, my advice to you is to either stay out of these particular chat channels or ignore them. You have nothing to gain by engaging in these chats and nothing to lose by disengaging from them.

Comment: I’m not sure if you understand the problem...if the OP outs themselves, the CEO themselves has openingly considered them ‘un-American and trying to destroy the country’...if you can’t predict that there will work place bullying when the OP ‘outs themselves’ then you surely can’t suggest this work environment *isn’t* toxic, or is simply one step away.

Comment: 1. Don't engage in these conversations. 2. Keep your opinions to yourself. 3. Ignore it. None of this is difficult. The OP put himself in this position by making his political views known. Stop doing that and people will stop directing attention to him.

Comment: To assume that they being quiet won’t open them up to bullying eventually is naive...eventually someone is going to wonder why the OP never says anything, dodges questions or only talks about work and doesn’t engage with the rest...for them, their open speaking is a form of bonding and the op isn’t....and they will eventually either straight up ask them, or start a witch hunt. No answer is still an answer to those looking for one.

Comment: How am I blaming the victim? I didn't say that any of this is his fault.

Comment: You literally said, *"The OP put himself in this position by making his political views known."*. First of all - they explicitely stated that they didn't, but the other parties did and second of all - this is the victim blaming part.

Comment: @joeqwerty OP stated that these chats are unavoidable and 40% of the chats pertain to work. Did you miss that when you read the question? In any case there is no choice other than to participate in the chats so your second point does not help.

Comment: I don't think you will have too much trouble navigating this situation, all you have to do is discuss politics when the topic is something you can agree with and tell everyone you are behind and need to focus on work when you disagree.  You can also tell a few white lies when it it's a borderline topic and just agree when you actually don't.  Sometimes keeping the peace is more important than getting involved in a discussion that doesn't really matter

Comment: @morbo: As much as I don't agree with the answer, there is a reasonable difference between a workplace that's toxic and one that's unwelcoming. Toxic workplaces require hostilities, be it passive or proactive. I fully agree that political discussions at work are always at risk of causing conflict, but expressing a political opinion in and of itself is not a sign of hostility when the environment up until now has been clearly welcoming of such opinions being uttered. If this is perpetuated after OP addresses it as an issue, I agree it's toxic. But for now, that part has not happened yet.