# How to deal with a politically biased workplace?

Tags: work-environment, politics

I know this topic has been posted before, however none of them really cover this situation.

My sister works with a local community college in the US that is very liberal left-leaning politically biased. All of her co-workers are left leaning but one of them is extremely sympathetic to the latest trends and insists on discussing and tossing around verbal "digs". The college insists on having CNN on every TV on the campus. There have been times when my sister has felt like there was political discrimination as well based on task assignments, etc. She's been working there for over 13 years and nothing has changed. At the end of the day, it becomes a hostile work environment. As a State employee and working there as long as she has, she gets great benefits and it would be devastating (medically speaking) if she had to leave. It's easy to say "not to discuss religion and politics in a workplace", but how does one deal with it when the entire workplace is biased?

Comment: Does this directly affect her work or cause her problems in the working environment? Is there any need for her to get involved? Does it really matter?

Comment: What specifically has been done to your sister that she considers political discrimination?

Comment: Gotta love how the post about the left-wing user involved outright bullying while this one is "there were opinions I don't like."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no specific question. It appears to be nothing more than trolling.

Comment: @Steve now that you mentioned it, this indeed looks like somewhat trollish counterpoint to [this recent closed question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/162530/168). As if someone read political discussion in its chat and decided to "test" how it would go if political sides were flipped

Comment: Deal with it the same way she has been for over a decade.

Answer (score 8):

By minding her own business. She doesn't need to indulge in political discussion and when anyone starts so, she can just leave the discussion by giving any excuse.

Comment: unfortunately, in many environs, you cannot step back, as the whole "Silence is violence", and "Silence is assent", sloganeering makes it impossible.

Answer (score 8):

how does "keeping up with trends" and having a news channel on the TV equate to a "hostile work environment"? also it would be great if you could provide some examples of these political "digs" you mentioned because as far as im concerned reading this i see absolutely no issue what so ever.

if she has worked there for 13 years and is only NOW voicing these concerns i think its less of the political side of things and more that she needs a break from the same old same old.